# How to find the function to which a line belongs with git?

Tags: git, grep, command-line-interface

I understand that `git grep -n <line>`
will give the function name to which that line belongs.
Also `git log -L 539,540:webpack/webpack.config.js` gives the commit history of lines 539-540 & `git log -L functionName:webpack/webpack.config.js` gives the commit history of the procedure functionName()

Is there a way to combine both of this and get the commit history of the function to which `539,549:webpack/webpack.config.js` belongs.
Essentially, a way to find to which function the lines belong would be enough.

Also this is not for manual viewing. I will be using this commands in a program to find the commit history of the function. So, checking the context and finding the function name and then using it is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried using the `--context` (or `-C`, for short) flag? If you tune the number of leading and trailing lines to your needs, you should be able to see the name of the function containing the match.

Comment: Hi, -C in grep or log?

Comment: Also, check the edit on the question. This is not for manual use.

Comment: If you want this to be programmatic, your approach will need to know about JS syntax. That's going to be more complicated...